# GCC: how to pause/continue compilation?

Tags: gcc

Is there an option to stop compilation and save state to a file and then load the file and continue compilation?

I know that GCC has `-fdump-gimple-tree` option, which makes GCC dump an internal representation "GIMPLE" to a file, but I cannot find an option to load the file back in.

Comment: Possible (bad) workaround: Use GCC inside a VM that you can pause and continue.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mat actually i want to use different versions of GCC at time. I have a patch to GCC 4.3.1, but also i need to use GCC plugin DragonEgg and  there is no plugins until GCC 4.5.0. I've tried to merge code of gcc 4.3.1 with patch and gcc 4.5.0 but failed. I think that is too difficult

Comment: Ofcourse, I would appreciate if anybody advice me how to do merging. I've used KDiff3.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few options:

- try to update your patch for 4.3.1 to 4.5.0 (do not try to merge the patched 4.3.1 code branch with the 4.5.0 code branch, that would be mayhem)

  try to get your patch to 4.3.1 to be included in the 4.5 release. If it fixes a bug, that should be possible (just file a _detailed_ report on the GCC bugzilla)

  try to modify your code so that it does not depend on that 4.3.1 patch or on the plugin infrastructure

Or... all of the above.

Trying to get your code halfway compiled partially by one version, then finished by another sounds completely hopeless.

Comment: most likely you're right that hopeless. Could you explain more detail about first option please? I can't apply patch to 4.5.0, right? Are you talking abote rewriting patch source for 4.5.0 version?

Comment: You should try to apply your patch the 4.5.0, and try to fix the rejects yourself. Alternatively, if the patch is short enough, just look at what it does and try to do the same thing on the 4.5.0 code. This is not easy to do if the patch is complex. And the GCC source is quite hard to get into. Unless your patch is a bugfix, the easiest option is probably the third one.

Comment: Can you advise gui patch tool?

Comment: I don't know any. Since you're asking that, I'll repeat what I said: the third option is very likely the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about stopping GCC compilation, but you can cache already compiled file so GCC won't have to compile them again. See [CCache](http://ccache.samba.org/).

So if you stop brutally the compilation at some time, say with Ctrl-C, when you start again, all files that were already compiled will be retrieved from the cache.